# Why is data from the Firebase realtime database only rendering in the console, but not on the page while using Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database, vuex

When I try to render a value stored in my Firebase Realtime Database, I can see it when I console.log, but it won't render on the page while using the {{ exams.name }} syntax in Vue. When I setup the same thing, but using Firestore, I was able to render it onto the page.

I am using this code in my main dashboard view:

```
import firebase from '@/firebase/firebaseConfig.js'
import db from '@/firebase/firebaseConfig.js'
import { database } from '@/firebase/firebaseConfig.js'

export default  {

  data() {
    return {
      checkpointReward: {},
      subscribersGained: {},
      ordersRecevied: {},
      salesBarSession: {},
      supportTracker: {},
      productsOrder: {},
      salesRadar: {},
      totalStudents: {},
      examRef: {},
      exams: {},
      studentName: {},
      students: {},
      testingData: {},
      analyticsData,
      dispatchedOrders: []
  }
},

   // Initialize Firebase
    const examRef = database.ref('exams');
        
      examRef.on('value', gotData, errData);

        function gotData(data) {
          const exams = data.val();
          const studentData = exams.name;
          console.log(exams.name);
        }

        function errData(err) {
          console.lof("Error!");
          console.log(err);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you pasted your code without some part of the component, but this part should be inside a method and assign the value to this.desired_state_value like so:

```
  export default  {

      data() {
        return {
         checkpointReward: {},
         subscribersGained: {},
         ordersRecevied: {},
         salesBarSession: {},
         supportTracker: {},
         productsOrder: {},
         salesRadar: {},
         totalStudents: {},
         examRef: {},


        [...]
     },
  methods: {
     getExams(){
        // Initialize Firebase
        this.examRef = database.ref('exams');
    
        this.examRef.on('value', gotData, errData);

        function gotData(data) {
           const exams = data.val();
           const studentData = exams.name;
           console.log(exams.name);
    }

      function errData(err) {
         console.lof("Error!");
         console.log(err);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am pretty new to Vue and JS in general :)

Comment: I was able to figure out a workaround just using Axios for the time being. Only issue is it seems to not be reactive in realtime on the frontend when I change the data in the database.